# Possible to hide cv-prefixed functions in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm using C++, and compiling & linking to OpenCV2 using "g++". One thing that bothers me is that all of the old cv-prefixed functions are still available and "pollute" my application.

Is it possible to make the OpenCV1 C cv-prefixed functions unavailable in the scope of my application and just keep the OpenCV2 `cv::` namespaced ones?

Note: I haven't written C in a while, so please let me know if this is a silly question.

Comment: Hide?  Like make private, like not show up in the autocomplete bar, or like rename?

Comment: @CodaFi make private, I suppose. To prevent them from being available in the scope of my application.

Comment: Do not #include the header files that declare them?

Comment: @brianbeuning Can't do. The OpenCV2 headers bring them in. So, I bring in `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"` and that pulls in `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"` which has all of the C, cv-prefixed, functions.

Comment: You could delete the #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h" in the header files of OpenCV. That might break functionality though.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev I don't think that's an option for me. I want to be able to depend on the user of my app to build his own opencv, and for my app to dynamically link to their version of the library. Yet, still not have to think about the cv* functions and constants polluting the scope of my app.

Comment: You could take the offending opencv header files, copy them in (project_dir)/inc_opencv and then change them in a way that doesn't include the C interface and use these headers. If you change the version of opencv you will have to repeat the process and it will not be portable. Actually I don't think that you could throw these functions out of scope without some ugly AND unportable hackery like that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you really need. If you just want to make this code:

```
CvArr *arr;
cvAvg(arr);
cvAcc(arr, arr);
```

"not working" - you can just add this:

```
#define cvAvg nothing_interesting_cvAvg
#define cvAcc nothing_interesting_cvAcc
//you can change nothing_interesting_... to anything, but you can't use the same text more than once
//you include files
//...
//after your include files
#undef cvAvg
#undef cvAcc
```

before including any OpenCV file. If you now try to compile code you will see:

```
error C3861: 'cvAvg': identifier not found
```

If you change you code to use `nothing_interesting_cvAvg(arr);` instead of `cvAvg(arr);`, it will compile fine, but linker will fail, because:

```
: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _nothing_interesting_cvAvg referenced in function _main
```

Note that this will work only for this 2 functions, so you will have to find all functions which you want to "disable" and write similar code manually.
Functions which use "deactivated" functions will work fine, because they are already compiled, linked, etc - you will just call them from some files without changing anything in this files.

Comment: Great, detailed answer; thank you. This would be a possible solution if my goal was to prevent someone on the team using the legacy prefixed functions (and I should clarify that that isn't). But this would not solve the problem of scope pollution, as it will stil have all of the `nothing_interesting_*` un-namespaced functions in the scope.